# Android thread cannot access Main.xml

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I am trying to use a thread to continuously take pictures. The problem is that I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to create my preview.

```
private class CameraThread extends ImageView implements Runnable
{
    ...
    public CameraThread(Context c)
    {
        super(c);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setFocusable(true);
        p = new Preview(c);
        Log.d(TAG,"preview null:"+(p==null));
        s = new SurfaceView(c);
        counter = 0;
        if(findViewById(R.id.preview)==null)
            Log.d(TAG,"preview view is null");
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(p);
        canvas = new Canvas();
        t = new TextView(c);

        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureButton);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                running = true;
                //new CaptureTask().execute();
            }
        });
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

The debugger points me to this line:

```
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(p);
```

I'm not sure why this is null. This code all worked fine from within the main activity. The Preview object does not come out as null, however the findViewById returns a null object.

Any thoughts?

EDIT

The thread is declared in the main activity. I'm modifying this code, this was originally implemented using buttons to capture individual pictures. I am trying to continuously take pictures.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mCameraThread = new CameraThread(this);
    setContentView(mCameraThread);
    Thread thread = new Thread(mCameraThread);
    thread.start();
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to me that you are calling `setContentView` in an ImageView, as I cannot find such a method in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). Also, an image is a View, not a ViewGroup, so it does not make sense to have other Views inside of it like you are doing.

If I were to guess I would recommend having a CameraActivity class, which extends Activity. In that activity's `onCreate` method you would set the content view as you are doing here. You would also probably use a different XML file for your CameraActivity, in which you define the ImageView to display on.

Could you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do?

I suggest you start checking out the android developer site. There is tons of great information on how to get started

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

EDIT:

Here is an introduction to threading on android: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

An AsyncTask is run in a ThreadPool, so there is no reason you cannot do your image processing there. It is basically a Thread with nice features such as communicating with the UI thread easily.

The reason you are getting that error message is that you are calling methods on a View outside of the UI thread. The link I provided gives some ways around that. If you continue to have problems post your code or a new question.

Comment: I don't see `setContentView` in [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) either. Was it in a previous API level?

Comment: I managed to get this kind of working using AsyncTask, but I'd rather use threads as I later want to implement some image processing. I'm just not very familiar with threads. When I had most of the methods implemented in the activity, I would get an error that the thread could not modify views it had not created, which is why I am trying to implement most of this in the thread.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information. You shouldn't be afraid to use an AsyncTask. The reason you get that error is because you try to modify a View outside of the UI thread.